# Using jQuery to access an element's text from an iframe hosted by Google Docs

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, google-docs

I'm writing a code segment to strip information out of an iframe hosting a google docs PowerPoint presentation. Basically, I need to note how long each user spends on each slide in the hosted doc, which means I need to know when they jump to a new slide to start the timer over. I figured I'd be able to do this by accessing the slide number within the iframe using jQuery, but I've learned that because of cross-domain scripting issues, this is no easy (if even possible) feat.

I've looked into using cross-domain messaging, but if I'm understanding correctly, that's a no-go because of my inability to control Google's servers (drat.) My next solution will probably be to turn the PowerPoints into PNG's and build a simple PNG viewer to give me full control, but if anyone has a solution where I could host the document on Google and still be able to monitor time spent on each slide, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You probably can create some div elements above your power point controls and keep track when you getting click inside that div.

Comment: Brilliant, I'll give this a shot and report back.

Comment: Doesn't look like it'll work - users are allowed to "jump" to different sections using a drop down menu. I still need to access the titles (or numbers) of the slides to make sure each slide is timed, and that the time gets attributed to the correct slide.

Comment: Or you can try to write some proxy script and place it at the same place with your application. So now all requests will be going to your domain not google.